# SQL command to join and count differnt items in a column grouping them

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
 select t1.ks, t1.[# Tasks], coalesce(t2.[# Late], 0) as [# Late]
 from 
(SELECT ks, COUNT(*) AS '# Tasks' FROM Table GROUP BY ks) t1
left join
(SELECT ks, COUNT(*) AS '# Late' FROM Table GROUP BY ks) t2
 on  t1.ks = t2.ks
```

this commands works well with only two columns but on my project i want 2 display up to eight columns of data. Can anyone help with such a command that produces results in the same manner as the one above but for eight columns.

Comment: You are applying group by so you need to decide what do you want from that other columns avg,sum,count,max,min or any random value

Answer (score 0):

You need logic to determine what makes something late.  Then, you can do what you want with conditional aggregation, because the fields you want appear to be from the same table:

```
select ks, count(*) as numprojects,
       sum(case when ***late condition goes there *** then 1 else 0 end) as numlate
from table t
group by ks;
```

Comment: oneA       oneB       oneC       oneD       oneE       oneF       oneG       
Excellent  Excellent  Excellent  Good       Excellent  Good       Excellent 
 Excellent  Excellent  Good       Good       Excellent  Good       Good      
Excellent  Good       Good       Fair       Fair       Good       Good           

Having table above can i have a command that counts values of each columnComment  oneA oneB oneC oneD oneE
Excellent 8     4   2    2    0
Good   2 6   4  7    9
Fair      0     0   4    1    1